# Interface scaling in full hd

Tags: settings, user-interface, high-dpi

I have a full hd screen, and my interface is too small. I can't find scaling in system settings. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scaling factors can be configured by `gsettings` in terminal (seen in [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1282847)):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1
```

You can play around with the values.

Comment: And what about different scaling on different monitors at one time?

Comment: That's a different question. Please edit your question or ask a new question for the sake of clear answers.

Comment: useless example since it is already set to 1 and it is an integer value (as far as I know).  The option is 1 or 2 and is available in the settings panel... not 1.25.  Please correct me if I am wrong.